# How to repeat LocalNotification Weekly in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to repeat a local notification weekly.

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "Notification"
notification.alertTitle = "Notification Title"
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Weekday
notification.fireDate = notificationDate 
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.category = "Events"

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

But this is repeat everyday instead of every week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear` instead of `NSCalendarUnit.Weekday`.

Note the difference between a `weekday` which denotes a day in week (that is, every day) and `weekOfYear` which denotes a week.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `notif.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfMonth`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!